# Solving Radicals in One Variable

Tags: radicals

I recently encountered a question from my math textbook (I write as a Grade 12 math student) which presented a radical equation to be solved. I did so, but in a messy way. Writing this question serves me the purpose of having it simplified.
The equation is simple: $160=\pi r \sqrt{36 + r^2}$.
My approach is:

\begin{align}
160 &=\pi r\sqrt{36 + r^2}\\
25600 &=\pi^2 r^2 (36 + r^2)\\
0 &= r^4 \pi^2 + 36r^2 \pi^2 - 25600\\
0 &= \pi^2(r^4 + 36r^2)  - 25600\\
0 &= \pi^2(r^4 + 36r^2 + 18^2) - 18^2 \pi^2 - 25600\\
0 &= \pi^2(r^2 + 18)^2 - 324\pi -  25600\\
\sqrt{\frac{25600 + 324\pi}{\pi^2}} &= r^2 + 18\\
r &= \sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{25600 + 324\pi}{\pi^2}}-18} \approx 6\\
\end{align}

The textbook gave an exact answer of 6. This prompted me to think there is a neater and "prettier" way of solving this equation. Please help.

Comment: Cross checking from the answer: $RHS=\sqrt{36+6^2}\cdot6\cdot\pi=159.943786\neq160=LHS$ surely your textbook's answer is not exact

Comment: @N.N. Maybe the textbook gave an answer of $6$ to $2$ decimal places?

Comment: Thank you. Even so, it took me awhile to arrive at the answer. Is there a faster way of solving this?

Comment: From your third line, notice that the equation is quadratic in $r^2. $

Comment: May be, at the second line, as a shortcut, they used $\pi^2\approx10$

Comment: Thank you for your answers but what I meant to ask is if anyone had a more elegant way of solving this equation.